# Symfony2 Hide Some Fields and Add Custom Fields

Tags: forms, symfony, customization

How can i achieve this:

1. I have an entity "**Users**" containing many fields along with two additional fields "created" and "modified" that store creation and modification date of the record. I don't want to display these two fields in "**new.html.twig**" and "**edit.html.twig**"
2. I want to add a virtual field in "new.html.twig" like "Confirm Password" that is actually not saved in database table.

Can anybody suggest a best tutorial for beginners that contain good example for each topic?

Comment: The symfony2 docs are quite comprehensive and easy to understand, even for a beginner.  You don't specify which version of symfony2 you are using (2.1, 2.2, 2.3?) so it's impossible to give specific advice.  Check out the sf2 docs.

Comment: i am using symfony 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to displayed each field manually don't use `{{ form(form) }}` .
2. Don't add virtual field, use [repeated](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) form element.